# Sorting query by importance, weight, and length

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, database

I have a database with a set of a 100 people, who all have a specific weight and length. 10 of these people have the status 'important'. I want to sort this list of people according to their weight (heavy to light), and if some people have the same weight they should be sorted by length (short to tall) accordingly.

There is one exception on this sorting order. The first 3 results should list the shortest 'important' people of the collection (sorted from short to long).

How could I write this in an SQL query?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images. Also show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find this problem rather challenging in MySQL.  I can think of a few different approaches:

- `union all`
- variables
- window function (not available in MySQL prior to 8.0)
- subqueries in the `order by` clause

None of these are trivial.  Here is one solution:

```
select t.*
from ((select t.*, 1 as which
       from t
       where status = 'important'
       order by height
       limit 3
      ) union all
      (select t.*, 2 as which
       from t
       where status = 'important'
       order by height
       limit 999999 offset 2
      )
     ) t
order by which,
         (case when which = 1 then weight end),
        weight, desc, length desc
```